# SQL Selecting the latest row using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, informix

An academic term that is using a semester system divides the year in two.

I've the following result from a SQL query, the term, as stated above, has its values from 1 to 2 always it also holds the score of the student (ID) for that specific term:

```
 ID | Year | Term | Career | Score
-----------------------------------
 1  | 2015 |  2   |   70   | 3,25
 1  | 2015 |  1   |   70   | 3,58
 2  | 2015 |  1   |   71   | 4,05
 2  | 2014 |  2   |   71   | 4,17
 3  | 2012 |  2   |   70   | 3,88
 3  | 2012 |  1   |   70   | 4,23
 3  | 2011 |  2   |   70   | 4,78
```

I want to return the corresponding row for the latest semester (year-term) for each student, so a result that would look like:

```
 ID | Year | Term | Career | Score
-----------------------------------
 1  | 2015 |  2   |   70   | 3,25
 2  | 2015 |  1   |   71   | 4,05
 3  | 2012 |  2   |   70   | 3,88
```

I'm making use of the GROUP BY clause with these particularities:

- Grouping by the 'ID'
- Selecting the MAX(Year)
- Selecting the MAX(Term)

The problem is that I need to keep the term to the corresponding year and the MAX(Term) clause is the one that causes the mistake. For instance, using the query I got now, the result is not true because it would return this row:

```
 ID | Year | Term | Career | Score
-----------------------------------
 2  | 2015 |  2   |   71   | 4,05
```

Instead of this one (which is the correct one):

```
 ID | Year | Term | Career | Score
-----------------------------------
 2  | 2015 |  1   |   71   | 4,05
```

How can I keep the correspondence between the (year-term)?

*As hint: 2015-2 is greater than 2015-1 and 2014-1 is greater than 2013-2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Informix does not offer `row_number()`.

Does the following work?

```
select t.*
from t
where year || term = (select max(t2.year || t2.term)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.id = t.id
                     );
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! By using this method I could achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the Updated date column. Using this column you can achieve whatever you want.